# Finding MIN value with other conditions Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql

I'm using Teradata SQL.

I have a table with these columns
orgprice - original price
sprice - sale price
saledate - sale date

I need to find * date of the earliest sale in the database where the sale price of the item did not equal the original price of the item*

I tried using MIN like this:

```
SELECT MIN(saledate)
FROM trnsact
WHERE orgprice <> sprice
```

but this just returned the min saledate value overall, the where clause was ignored.

How do I do this ?

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results -

Comment: Your query should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT col1,col2,MIN(case when orgprice <> sprice then saledate end)
FROM trnsact 
group by col1, col2
```

Comment: This also returned the same result. Could you tel me how I can select more columns with this query so I can check if it's actually returning a different entry.

Comment: @AnantSinha, I've edited the answer to select column - you can check

Answer (score 1):

Simple task for ranking:

```
SELECT *
FROM trnsact
WHERE orgprice <> sprice
QUALIFY
   ROW_NUMBER()
   OVER (-- PARTITION BY item -- ?
         ORDER BY saledate) = 1
```

For a single row you might also use TOP:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM trnsact
WHERE orgprice <> sprice
ORDER BY saledate
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I think there must be another answer.
1. The query took minutes to execute, I had to cancel it. I'm solving an academic assignment and they didn't give us a problem that would take this long
2. Why is there a PARTITION BY clause? I just need one row

Comment: I didn't know if this was for each item or globally, that's why I wrote `PARTITION BY item -- ?`. Simply remove that part.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, your table also has an "item" column to define the item.  If so, you just need a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT item, MIN(saledate)
FROM trnsact
WHERE orgprice <> sprice
GROUP BY item;
```